# smarty plugin return array

Tags: php, smarty

I am creating a plugin that returns a array to the template file. I can't seem to get the full array to be parsed to the template file.

plugin function.arraytest

```
function smarty_function_arraytest($params,Smarty_Internal_Template $template)
{
    $x = array("1"=>array("categories"=>"Action"));
     return $x
}
```

template file

```
{arraytest}
```

result
array

I cannot seem to iterate through the array in the template file.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything returned by a smarty function gets output directly, the .tpl never actually gets the array, just the string value "Array". It has been a long time since I used Smarty so this may have changed, but I believe the standard way of doing it is like this:

```
function smarty_function_arraytest($params, $template)
{
    // check $params['out'] exists here
    $array = array("1"=>array("categories"=>"Action"));
    $template->assign($params['out'], $array);
}
```

then call it like:

```
{arraytest out="arraytestValues"}
{foreach from=$arraytestValues key=k item=v}
   <p>{$k}: {$v}</p>
{/foreach}
```

of course, because you have a multidimensional array you'll need to loop over it twice:

```
{arraytest out="arraytestValues"}
{foreach from=$arraytestValues key=k item=v}
   <p>{$k}: {$v}</p>
    {foreach from=$v key=sk item=sv}
        <p>{$sk}: {$sv}</p>
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Thank you very much... have been banging my head for a couple of hours lol.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it help:

```
{assign var=arr value=arraytest}
{$arr....}
```

Then docs:
http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.syntax.variables.tpl

Comment: Right answer is below, from @pjumble ))